# Where can I find my jar on Apache Flink server which I submitted using Apache Flink dashboard

Tags: apache-flink

I developed a Flink job and submitted my job using Apache Flink dashboard. Per my understanding, when I submit my job, my jar should be available on Flink server. I tried to figure out path of my jar but couldn't able to. Does Flink keep these jar file on server? If yes, where I can find? Any documentation? Please help. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JAR files are renamed when they are uploaded and stored in a directory that can be configured with the `web.upload.dir` [configuration key](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.6/ops/config.html#web-frontend).

If the `web.upload.dir` parameter is not set, the JAR files are stored in a dynamically generated directory under the `jobmanager.web.tmpdir` (default is `System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir")`).

Comment: Thank you Fabian Hueske for helping me out!

Comment: My pleasure. You could accept the answer if it answered your question.

Comment: I looked into my "jobmanager.web.tmpdir" directory and found my jar. Though one more question related to this. When I see my Flink dashboard,
I can see around 10-12 jobs are running but all these jars are NOT present in "jobmanager.web.tmpdir". Seems like when job is submitted and jars are being remove from Flink dashboard,
it also get remove from "jobmanager.web.tmpdir" directory. Where I can find other jars which are running but removed from Flink dashboard?

Comment: @Shailendra I was troubled for the same thing until I found the Flink BlobServer thing. It looks like Flink stores jars under a folder named as `blobStore-<hash>` under `System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir")`, for simple local setup. The jar files are renamed with a hash and no longer ends with `.jar`.